# Flexbox grandchild overflowing grandparent's height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flexbox in a side navigation that is overflowing it's granparent's height. The basic structure is:

```
<div class="holder">
  <div class="block-item">content</div>
  <div class="flex-nav">
   <div class="flex-row"><img src="#"><img src="#"></div>
   <div class="flex-row"><img src="#"><img src="#"></div>
   <div class="flex-row"><img src="#"><img src="#"></div>
   <div class="block-item">content</div>
  <div>

.holder { height: 100vh;}
.block-item { display: block;}
.flex-nav { display: flex;  flex-flow: column;}
.flex-row { flex: 1 1 0; display: flex;}
img { max-width: 100%;}
```

Somehow the flex-rows are not shrinking to fit their grandparent's 100vh.  Instead, the images are going outside of the view port.  From the articles I've read, I'm not sure if a grandchild takes into consideration it's grandparent's height restrictions, though I'm assuming it would.  The actual code is slightly different and can be seen in the following codepen:

http://codepen.io/strasbal/pen/zNEMpj?editors=1100

However I'm not sure the exact specifications of Codepen's viewport, it may not show when changes are put into place, so the site url is http://www.webhosting-issues.com

Comment: Question not entirely clear to me. Related? http://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276

Comment: It's more that I want everything to stay in the view port but the content is extending past it.  What I'm trying to create is a side navigation that fits and stays the height of the viewport.  Somehow the flexbox grandchild is going past the height set by its grandparent.  So instead of having the side bar fit the viewport window, the user has to scroll to see the whole thing.  I'm using relative units for the images, so everything should shrink to fit the viewport, but for some reason it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had already set the height of the overall container at 100vh, you can assign a height in vh units to the header and footer that let them maintain the heights they already were, and then do the math to fill in the heights of other child elements.

- Overall container is 100vh
- Header logo and contact footer are 19vh each
- That leaves 62vh for the middle section, made up of three rows
- That's 20.666vh per row in the middle section

From there, just set explicit heights for the images and their wrapper links for the inner rows, and you’re was good to go.

One problem you run into is that the text in the links by the images can run out of their container on smaller screens. You could fix that by putting them inside spans and positioning them on top of the images, perhaps with a semi-transparent background.

Hope that works for you.

```js
document.getElementById("contact-us").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("contact-us").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut()
};

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("contact-button").style.color = "black";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("contact-button").style.color = "white";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100%; /* NEW! */
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

header {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo,
#contact-us {
  background: #074f7b;
  padding: 0.5em;
  height: 19vh; /* NEW! */
}

#logo h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 68%;
}

#logo img {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding-left: .4em;
  color: white;
}

#logo::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

flex-holder {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column no-wrap;
}

nav {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

nav:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-row {
  display: flex
}

.nav-row li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 20.666666vh; /* NEW! */
  width: 50%; /* NEW! *//* helps make the boxes line up correctly, not needed for layout*/
}

.nav-row a {
  display: block;
  padding: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  width: 100%; /* NEW! */
  height: 100%; /* NEW! */
}

.nav-row a:hover {
  color: white;
}

#site-down {
  background: #ffc219;
}

#wordpress {
  background: #8f73b4;
}

#migrations {
  background: #0778bb;
}

#backups {
  background: #f06f26;
}

#databases {
  background: #764821;
}

#domains {
  background: #59bb53;
}

#contact-us h1,
#contact-us img {
  color: white;
}

#contact-us {
  text-align: center;
}

#contact-us img {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 .5em
}

#contact-us div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact-us h2 {
  color: white;
  margin: 0em 0em .5em 0em;
  padding-left: 0.625em
}

#contact-us::after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}

#contact-us button {
  background: #8f73b4;
  border-radius: .6em;
  border: 1px solid #8f73b4;
  color: white;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  flex: 2;
  overflow: auto;
}

#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

article h1,
article p {
  margin: 1.563em;
}

article h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<doctype="HTML">
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>Web Hosting Issues</title>
    <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <header>
        <div id="logo">
          <a href="home">
            <h1>Web Hosting <br>Issues</h1>
            <img src="http://webhosting-issues.com/images/whi-logo.png" alt="Web Hosting Issues Logo">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-holder">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <div class="nav-row">
                <li id="site-down">
                  <a href="site-down-url">
                    <img src="http://webhosting-issues.com/images/site-down.png" alt="Web Site Down Article Link ">Site Down
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="wordpress">
                  <a href="wordpress-url">
                    <img src="http://webhosting-issues.com/images/wordpress.png" alt="Wordpress Troubleshooting Article Link ">Wordpress
                  </a>
                </li>
              </div>
              <div class="nav-row">
                <li id="migrations">
                  <a href="migrations-url">
                    <img src="http://webhosting-issues.com/images/migrations.png" alt="Hosting Migration and Transfer Article Link ">Migrations
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li id="backups">
                  <a href="backups-url">
                    <img src="http://webhosting-issues.com/images/backups.png" alt="Website Backups Article Link ">Backups
                  </a>
                </li>
              </div>
              <div class="nav-row">
                <li id="databases">
                  <img src="http://webhosting-issues.com/images/databases.png" alt="Troubleshooting MySQL Databases Article Link ">Databases

                </li>
                <li id="domains">
                  <a href="domains-url">
                    <img src="http://webhosting-issues.com/images/domains.png" alt="Troubleshooting Domain Hosting Article Link ">Domain
                  </a>
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div id="contact-us">
            <a href="contact-form">
              <img src="whi-superhero" alt="Contact Us to Fix your Website Issues">
              <div>
                <h2>Have Us Fix It</h2>
                <button id="contact-button">Contact Us</button>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
      <article>
        <div id="inner">
          <h1>Article Title</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mei hinc graeci vituperatoribus et. Pri stet copiosae mediocrem eu. Mollis inimicus mel id, mutat mentitum vix an. No pro virtute intellegam, ea has epicurei referrentur, posse oporteat ius ei.</p>
          <p>Libris appellantur et pro. Insolens ocurreret salutatus et sit. Mei ea aeque ludus aliquando, at hinc ponderum comprehensam cum. Eu nam mandamus expetenda dissentiunt, probo tacimates at eos, no everti docendi sed. Id appetere democritum nam.</p>
          <p>Odio animal aperiam ea sit. Debet accumsan ne pro, eos simul perfecto invenire ea. Per ea quaestio consulatu. Eos vide repudiare id, mei cu ridens possim assentior, te probo intellegat vim. Has etiam incorrupte an. Id oratio verear audire mei,
            reque tincidunt duo ex.</p>
          <p>Eum erant putant vocent ei. At dico exerci quo. Pri melius ocurreret persequeris in, eu noster virtute est. Aeque commodo ut duo. In sit melius dignissim, te has lorem minimum consectetuer.</p>
          <p>Pri oratio vocibus vituperatoribus te, dolores persecuti sit ut. Esse munere eam ea, possim mentitum moderatius nec at. Doming gubergren ut mei, luptatum salutatus scriptorem mei an. Nec partem ponderum assueverit cu, veri erat libris his ad,
            ad vidisse docendi ius. At everti dolores disputationi vel, nec cu diceret eleifend. Pri cu falli erant, tamquam democritum ad sit, vis illum inani in. Apeirian nominati sed at, ei atomorum accommodare usu, has modus definitionem te.</p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing.  Thank you so much!  I didn't even think of having the sizes add up to the containers viewport.  I'm going to do a slightly different look for mobile, so this is exactly what I needed.